# preventSwapBefore token contracts

Tags: tokens, uniswap, state-variable, liquidity

I'm looking for a way to determine to determine tokens' contract private state variables such as _preventSwapBefore, or _reduceTaxAt, etc... Theese variables or often in token's contract, but in private, and not always in the same order. I need to find them through my program directly, without reading the contract. The fact that they are not always at the same place in storage makes the use of get_storage_at pretty useless x) Does anyone have an idea ?